# In Wicket, what is the difference between the different get input methods?

Tags: methods, wicket

What is the difference between getRawInput, getValue() and getModelValue() etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Method names without what class they're in sort of leave us guessing.

I'll assume these are all in org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent, as they do all exist there.

All are related to data entered by a user on a form, but roughly speaking, getRawInput() is data from the user, getModelValue() is the value in the current model for the form component, and getValue() is either of these depending on whether the user actually supplied data.

These methods are all documented in [the javadoc for FormComponent](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html)